# Cómo guardar la ejecucion de un programa en un archivo del computador

Tags: python, base-de-datos, pickle

Estoy desarrollando un software de Ingeniería Civil el lenguaje de programación python y me encuentro en la necesidad de realizar **guardado de la ejecución del programa** para más tarde poder abrir nuevamente la ejecucion del programa. Algo así como cuando se crea un documento en Word o Excel y se guarda en un archivo .docx/.xlsx.

He revisado y encuentro que es posible mediante archivo binario utilizando la librería pickle, sin embargo también he leido que es posible guardar utilizando un archivo de texto Normal como cualquier otro archivo de texto y luego el usuario lo puede abrir leyendo es archivo de texto. También he leído que es posible guardar información mediante base de datos SQLite y también es posible generar hasta archivos .xml.

Creo que todas que las opciones anteriores es posible guardar y Leer la información y mi consulta a la comunidad es:

1. Cuál es la mejor forma o la más comun para resolver el problema (no tengo gran experiencia en desarrollo de software, soy ingeniero civil); mediante serializacion, archivos de texto con la funcion open inventando una extensión o creando archivos base de datos o XML ?
2. En el caso de crear archivos de texto, ¿ exista en programación una estructura de buena practica de como guardar los datos ?. Es decir, primero el nombre de software, luego la version, luego la fecha, hora y luego los datos ingresado durante la ejecución del programa ?. En este caso se crea el código definiendo dicha estructura recorriendo toda la información durante ejecucion y luego otro código para leer la información y asignar a las variables durante otra ejecución.

Agradezco mucho la experiencia de alguien en el mundo desarrollo software de escritorio.

Gracias

Comment: Me imagino que cualquier opción que elijas esta bien. Usa la que mas te guste o veas mas sencilla de usar.

Comment: Tal cual tu pregunta está, que no te sorprenda que la cierren. Aquí unas recomendaciones sobre cómo preguntar para que tengas más chances de obtener respuesta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Como tienes más de 25 puntos de reputación, ven a la sala de chat donde es libre la temática. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol Saludos.

Comment: pickle es la forma estándar de salvar variables a disco, suele ser también el método más rápido. Serializar en archivos de texto, puede ser útil si necesitas ver o editar estos valores de forma externa, lo más común es ir a un formato tipo json.

Comment: Por otro lado coincido con fredy, date una vuelta por el chat, dónde puedes tranquilamente pedir opiniones. Suerte.